# Why does ActiveRecord return an empty array after raising a StatementInvalid error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

```
specify 'Test' do
  Foo.create

  expect( Foo.count ).to eq 1

  expect{ ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute( 'invalid sql' )}
    .to raise_error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'ROLLBACK'

  expect( Foo.count ).to eq 1
end
```

This causes the following failure:

```
Failure/Error: expect( Foo.count ).to eq 1

   expected: 1
        got: 0
```

After the `StatementInvalid` error is raised, App.all returns an empty array. So, it seems that the error has poisoned future AR DB calls.

Where is this error coming from? Is there a way to reset the AR connection to fix this?

ActiveRecord 4.1.7 and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is there a reason for the rollback in the middle of your test? do you not think that's the culprit?

Comment: Yes, that's the culprit. I assumed that when a `create` succeeds, it commits the transaction. That is not how Rails works.

Comment: The reason to rollback is to "clear" the error in PostgreSQL. Otherwise, the next DB query will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the save process is wrapped in a transaction and the outermost save (in case the save callbacks, associations etc perform more database updates) commits the transaction when it commits.

In tests, this is typically not what happens: transactions are used to prevent individual tests from changing the database (rails has builtin support for this and the database_cleaner gem is also popular). Your manual 'rollback' statement is thus rolling back your call to create.

Comment: This answer was very helpful. I am using Database Cleaner with transactions.